# Stunnel as a transparent proxy

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy, stunnel

I am interested in the following setup

firefox->(local) stunnel client-> (remote) stunnel server->forwarded to internet

I thought this would be possible if I made my stunnel client connect to stunnel server, and the server's service had "transparent=destination" option set. However,when I do this, I think I am seeing in the logs where I get stuck in a loopback, because stunnel server thinks the final destination IS the stunnel server, since that's what the stunnel client was connecting to.

In the scenario I want to use, is stunnel really meant for firefox to connect directly to the remote end, and then that process would transparently forward to whatever website I was trying to get to? Can I even configure this in firefox, because it doesn't have just an "SSL Proxy" option does it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i don't think stunnel by itself can do this job . maybe you need combine it with a socks5 service . like this .

local firefox with socks5 proxy set to local:123 , wanting http://example.com/ ->

local stunnel listening on port 123 , encrypting with ssl , and forwarding to remote:456 ->

remote stunnel listening on port 456 , decrypting with ssl , and forwarding to remote:789 ->

remote socks5 service listening on port 789 , handles the proxy request , connecting to example.com via http .

---

stunnel is a **one-to-one** ssl wrapper , but when we browse the web , we perform requests to *many* *different* *hosts* . thus we have to do something to **dispatch** these different requests , which is a work stunnel can't handle .